# Why does iTunes only recognize some songs from a purchased album as being purchased?

Tags: itunes, icloud

Now that iTunes in the Cloud is available, my iPhone (iOS 5.0) and my MacBook Air (10.7.1 / iTunes 10.5) will show me lists of all the songs I've ever purchased through iTunes. It *almost* works great: I even found an album I'd completely forgotten I owned.

But I've noticed that at least one album (Muse - Absolution, [which *is* still available](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/album/absolution/id314261338) on the Canadian iTunes Store), despite having purchased the entire album way back when, only registers a single song (Blackout) as a purchase.

**Update:** Having looked at a bunch of other albums (and testing downloading one) this is actually rampant across my collection: sometimes all but one, sometimes only a couple of tracks are available from albums that I've purchased, and which are still in the store... Ironically, one of the few albums that will let me download it in its entirety is **not** in the Canadian iTunes Store!

**Update:** Sounds like this has been happening [since beta, and is still going on](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3104151?start=15&tstart=0).

I received an update from iTunes "support", by which I mean someone they've hired to read pages from their support site to me. The response: tracks which have been removed or modified can no longer be downloaded. Well, many of my tracks haven't been removed, so they must have been "modified". When I asked for clarification as to what modifications cause purchased tracks to no longer register, they provided me with this helpful explanation:

> The item has been modified since you purchased it, and no longer
>   available for download. It is not possible to redownload items that
>   has being modified within the store.

Thanks for clearing that up. I'm going to start over with another ticket and see if I can squeeze *anything* useful out of them.

**Update Update:** As of today, the Muse album I mentioned has been restored; I can now download all tracks. However, the other affected albums have not changed. Is this because I complained about this album in particular? Do I need to do the same for every other problem purchase? Will this slowly resolve itself over time? *Who knows?*

**Update, Nov. 13, 2011:** As of tonight, all my purchased music is once again available. I did not open a case with Support, so I can only chalk this up to fluctuations in the Store that have been resolved (perhaps as we approach the launch of iTunes Match). It's unlikely we'll ever have a definitive answer to this question, though the comments here may be useful to future visitors.

Comment: I am also having a similar problem. I recently upgraded to iOS 5 on my iPhone 4. Since then, on my iPhone there are one or two songs missing from at least 14 of my albums that i bought off iTunes months ago. The strange thing is when i look at those albums in 'Purchased' it doesn't show those missing songs as available to download even though they are available to download through the iTunes store. Yes i could re-download the missing songs from the iTunes store, but then i will get charged again. I know this because i've already tried with one of the missing songs.

Comment: I'm living in France (this is a different iTunes Store) and I have the same problem with different proportions (entire albums or even artist I can't redownload). I'm in the middle of a slow e-mail discussion with an iTunes support person, and I'm having a hard time to make her understand the problem. There are even songs that were available a few days ago that are unavailable right now. I'll let you know if I can grab any information…

Comment: Yeah, I'm still having the same odd behaviour: albums that weren't there are now complete, albums that were complete are gone, sometimes except for one or two songs. Hoping this is just instability associated with the coming rollout of iTunes Match; once that lands, I'll be much more concerned with this issue, as it'll influence (I assume) what I'm credited with having purchased for matching purposes!

Comment: Update on this : I've reported the error to the iTunes Support. They reset my account's password to do some *testing* and a few days later I can download all of my purchased articles. It took a while, though, but it works for my past purchases. I'll let you guys know if something happens with my future purchases.