# Some items missing from my iTunes Purchase History

Tags: itunes, icloud

I purchased some audio books and movies on the iTunes store before  (2-3 years ago).

But when I use the new iPhone 4S to look at my account, the "Purchased" show 1 audio book but doesn't show the other one I can clearly remember (in fact, I purchased that audio book twice, hoping the second time won't be any charge, but there was).

Also missing are some movies, such as Toy Story...  Is the only thing I can do to contact Apple iTunes Store Customer Service to resolve this?

Comment: I'm having [a very similar problem](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27571/8823). Sadly, no resolution yet. Then again, I haven't tried calling support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the best way I found, is to use the Express Lane.  Just google for: Apple Express Lane and you will find it.

Comment: I've contacted Apple Support and received what I would diplomatically call a "non-helpful" response. Would you elaborate on exactly what steps you went through and how they resolved the issue, please? I'm eager to have this fixed as well. Thanks! :)

Comment: I just went through the flow on that webpage, and then use something like "iTunes -> Report Missing Purchased Items" and somebody contacted me and found out my order and gave the content back to me (either make it on my song list or enqueue the video for me to download).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - movies are not yet available via the iTunes "Purchased" tab for re-download.  Only TV series are so far.  I think Apple is still negotiating the rights to allow movie downloads multiple times after purchase.

Comment: A while later I know, but this sounds like total BS as tvos has absolutely had to re-download movies. Paying for iTunes match should guarantee all your downloads barring podcasts.   Some years ago they did alter terms and conditions to say they could not do it in perpetuity, but this is the service they sell.